# Unable to send email from tomcat on google Composite engine

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

I followed all the steps from Google Cloud tutorial and I am able to send email from my local after authenticating the url printed on the console. Now I deployed my app on Tomcat of Composite Engine and when trying to send email, it's crashing the Tomcat server.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java

Struggling for almost a week to send the email from my Java app. Tried Mailgun service to integrate my Gsuite account but the steps are not helping. Feeling lost after trying everything I got on Google  Developer Portal. Please help with some working tutorial.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970827/sending-mail-from-apache-tomcat

Comment: that example is for tomcat server locally, I am able to setup  everything locally but on compute engine I am getting proxy error and its crashing the tomcat server